# I want to chain the"standard" output stream (System.out) to PrintWriter stream. But I can not. Why?

Tags: java, stream, chaining

I wanted replaced:

```
System.out.println("It works properly");
```

by:

```
PrintWriter myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
myPrintWriter.print("This text is not displayed on my screen");
```

Unfortunately this second options does not work and I do not why. I am learning Java from scratch and I am trying to understand some basics problems, concepts so... please, help. And sorry for my English ;)

Comment: `new PrintWriter(System.out, true);`

Comment: Note that `System.out` is a `PrintStream` which has *almost the same* semantics as a `PrintWriter`.  So `new PrintWriter(System.out)` may not be a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream is not flushed automatically. Use `myPrintWriter.flush()` to get the result on the console.

**Demo:**

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintWriter myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        myPrintWriter.print("This text is not displayed on my screen");
        myPrintWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
This text is not displayed on my screen
```